# Binding Controls to BindingSource in UserControl with Public Property VB.net

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I have a DataGridView and two TextBoxes with a DatePicker on my usercontrol in VB.Net. Also a datatable that filled from SQL Server.

I want to fill DataGridView with one field of my datatable and binding textboxes and datepicker with related fields of my datatable so that when user select each field of DataGridView, related value shown in textboxes and DatePicker.

My code:

```
Partial Public Class Form1
Shared Sub New()
    DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register()
End Sub
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyValidControl()
End Sub

Sub MyValidControl()
    Try
        Dim Rec As New MyProject
        MyDatePicker.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("DateTime", Rec, Rec.ChDate, True))
        TextEdit1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("EditValue", Rec, Rec.PayTo, True))
        TextEdit2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("EditValue", Rec, Rec.Description, True))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Rec
        
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

and Properties:

```
Public Class MyProject
Inherits Form1
Dim Binding1 As New BindingSource

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    Dim Tap As New DataSet1TableAdapters.ChequeTableAdapter
    Dim Dat As New DataSet1.ChequeDataTable
    Dim Binding1 As New BindingSource
    Binding1.DataSource = Dat

End Sub

Private _ChDate As Date
Private _Description As String
Private _PayTo As String
Private _IDCheque As String
Public Property ChDate() As Date
    Get
        Return _ChDate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        _ChDate = CType(value, Date)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Description() As String
    Get
        Return _Description
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Description = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property PayTo() As String
    Get
        Return _PayTo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _PayTo = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property IDCheque() As String
    Get
        Return _IDCheque
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _IDCheque = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

But I don't know what is the problem.
Notice: My datatable has 4 fields. PayTo, Description and ChDate are string and i have to convert ChDate to Date format for binding to DatePicker.
Please Help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why `_ChDate = CType(value, Date)` When the value passed to the `Set` is a date?

Comment: Since 2015 we have been using Auto-Implemented properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties

Comment: The class level variable Bindings1 is never used.

Comment: Your class inherits Form1. Where is the class that inherits UserControl?

Comment: What Mary has said is all 100% valid, but the thing is we don't know what the problem is either, you haven't actually told us what isn't working.  Exceptions, unexpected behaviors/results?

Comment: @Mary My reason to chose this approach: ChData Field is String in vb.net and nvarchar in SQL and I had to change it with  _ChDate = CType(value, Date) to bind to my customized DatePicker. Other wise i can bind controls to BindingSource in normal conditions. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @R.Salehi Your setter is `Set(ByVal value As Date)` so, before the value even hits the `_ChDate = CType(value, Date)' it must already be a date. No conversion is necessary. The value must be a valid date before your do the assignment. If you use a DateTimePicker the .Value property will always be a DataTime.

Comment: @Mary Is it possible to complete my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mary Thanks but I don't know what is the problem actually. Sorry

Comment: Well, I have pointed out several problems in my comments. Can you reply to my questions? Are you getting an error? What is the error message? Is something not behaving as you expect? Explain.

Comment: @Mary Yes, Cannot bind to the property or column ChDate on the DataSource. Also grid view doesn't show any things.

Comment: Where do you actually load the data from database?

Comment: @AlexB. Yes. From SQL. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you didn´t provide the code for that. Is the datasource dat filled correctly?

Comment: @AlexB. I am sure about filling datasource. Thanks